# Properties yearly costs

Tags: single-word-requests

My native language is Swedish and I work as a web-developer. I am currently working on a real estate website, which is written in English.

I am wondering what you call the yearly costs of a property (for example the cost for electricity, for heating the property). I am looking for a word that describes "The property's yearly costs" (in US-EN).

Comment: Commercial real estate or residential?

Comment: I should be Residential :)

Comment: Would overheads be too vague for this use?

Comment: Are you looking for **Annual service charges** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak to American lingo.

The problem is that the terms don't neatly partition the costs.  In the case of mortgage holders, the basic cost is the one that lenders calculate, and it goes by the term of art "PITI," which stands for "**P**rincipal, **I**nterest, **T**axes, **I**nsurance."  The first two are payments on the mortgage, the third is property tax, and the last is insurance required by the terms of the loan (casualty insurance and possibly mortgage repayment insurance).

In commercial real estate, people talk about "operating expenses," but homeowners aren't considered operators for tax purposes.  Similar terms for residential property are "recurring expenses" or "carrying costs."  Both of these would cover expenditures for water and sewer service (usually municipal operations), utilities (usually private operations like electrical and natural gas service), garbage collection, and routine maintenance.  Unfortunately, both terms apply to the inevitably recurring taxes and insurance, which are included in PITI.

You might try "other recurring expenses" or "other carrying costs."  (I'm assuming here that you break out PITI separately.)  I realize that's not a single-word answer.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, on property listings, the cost of electricity, oil, gas would often appear as a line-item labeled "utilities".  It is only an estimate, since it depends on consumption (weather, temperature settings, etc) and current prices.